# Ember issue with routes and parameters

Tags: ember.js

I am running into an issue setting up routes.  I have a route group of

this.route('users', function () {

for

```
/users

/users/add
```

as well this.route('users', {path: '/users/:user_id'}, function () {

for routes like

```
/users/1/edit

/users/1/goals

/users/1/goals/1
```

The issue I have is that {{#link-to 'users'}}Users{{/link-to}} results in a link to "/users/undefined", which causes other issues, it needs to be "/users".  Is there a way to do routes like this or would I be forced to have "users" and "user" route groups?

My routes:

```
this.route('users', function () {
  this.route('add');
});

this.route('users', {path: '/users/:user_id'}, function () {
  this.route('edit');
  this.route('goals', function(){
    this.route('add');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:goal_id/edit'});
  });
});
```

UPDATE:
ended up with

```
this.route('users', function () {
  this.route('add');
});

this.route('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'}, function () {
  this.route('edit');
  this.route('goals', function(){
    this.route('add');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:goal_id/edit'});
  });
});
```

Also I needed to fix my branch route js, and learn about this.modelFor('user') to get parent model since params are consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to try nesting routes.  It might look something like this:

```
this.route('users', function () {
  this.route('add');
});

this.route('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'}, function () {
  this.route('edit');
  this.route('goals', function(){
    this.route('add');
  });
  this.route('goal', {path: '/goal/:goal_id', function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I am nesting, I am not sure how to do the nesting if I need multiple parameters, but sometimes have 0 or 1.

Comment: @Xeridea - I updated this to match your new request.

Comment: Ended up having user and users seperate like this, though goals is together.  My other issue ended up being not having proper branch route and needed to access parent model from a goal.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the paths with parameters only need to be on those routes that always have an ID in them:

```
this.route('users', function () {
  this.route('add');
  this.route('edit', {path: '/:id/edit'});
  this.route('goals', {path: '/:id/goals'}, function() {
    this.route('add');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:goal_id/edit'});
  });
});
```

Comment: This would work except for users.goals.add I need to know the user id to associate to. +1 anyway.  This way would be cleaner if it would work though.

Comment: You can get the user ID from the params hash `params[:id]`